# Creating a dictionary by setting a list of type string to a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I am trying to create this dictionary using a List of type string (productIds) but it is erroring:

**The part that is erroring is p => p:**
*Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'*

It doesn't make sense to me since p => p makes it so I am passing a string into the first param and then a new list of product categories into the second param.

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> missingProducts =
    productIds.ToDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(
        p => p, p => p 
        new List<string>(productCategories));
```

Here is a working example in VB.NET that I am trying to convert over:

```
Dim productCategories As IList(Of String) = (From pc In prodCategories Select pc.CategoryName).ToList()

Dim missingProducts As Dictionary(Of String, IList(Of String)) = productIds.ToDictionary(Of String, IList(Of String))(Function(p) p, Function(p) New List(Of String)(productCategories))
```

Comment: Show the complete code...

Comment: looks like you need: `missingProducts = productIds.ToDictionary(p=>p,  new List<string>(productCategories))`, but not really sure what is `productIds`, if it is a `List<string>` what would you achieve by assigning all ids  the same product categories.

Comment: I suspect productIds is a list of integers, in which case you would need p => p.ToString()

Comment: productIds is just a list of type string with numbers in it like this: "1", "2", "89" and so on. So I shouldn't need to do .ToString().

Answer (score 6):

The second parameter of `ToDictionary` is a `Func` too (first: key selector, second: value selector), so you have to pass in `p` in too.

Second: the [signature of the call to `ToDictionary` is wrong](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657(v=vs.95).aspx):

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> missingProducts =
productIds.ToDictionary<string, string, IEnumerable<string>>(
    p => p, 
    p => new List<string>(productCategories));
```

Comment: While this works and fixes the compilation issue, I'm struggling to see the point in a dictionary that returns the same value for each key.

Comment: I wouldn't agree more. This might be a start to fix the second expression, but there is not too much about that in the question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that part. It is still erroring at the p in parenthesis: p => (p), p => new List<string>(productCategories));

Comment: So what is `productCategories`?

Comment: A list of ProductCategory objects. It would probably help if you see the working VB version which I added since I am converting it to a new app.

Comment: Then how you wanted to convert that to a list of strings?

Comment: Err I'm so sorry it is a list of string also like this: "Cars", "Boats", etc. The end goal here should be a dictionary that links each productId with a list of its product categories.

Comment: Are you sure? Why do you wrap it in a new list then?

Comment: @JTunney this is equivalent to your VB version.  You can paste it into a VB.NET to C# converter online and get the same code.  What's your error?  You mention a p in parenthesis - there is none in the code in this answer.

Comment: @jtu did you mean: `productCategories.Select(x=>x.Name)`?

Comment: Nope productCategories is set before hand. It is nothing but a string list of category names.

Comment: And what if you use it directly? `p=> productCategories`

Comment: And why didn't you use `IList` as in your current code?

Comment: the first part that I put in brackets still errors with the error message in my post: (p => [p], p = > productCategories) which is weird because thats the part that should just take a string not sure why it is worried about IEnumerable.

Comment: Are you sure `productIds` isn't the problem?

Comment: I thought for a second that was it but how would it be the problem since doing p => p for a list of string is just like looping through a list of string and getting each individual string isn't it? It isn't like I'm trying to put a IEnumerable<string> in that first param.

Comment: Aha!  The type parameters on `ToDictionary` are `TSource, TKey` - [they're backwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  I suggest you simply remove them as they're inferred.

Comment: After all that.. this works.. does this make sense: var missingProducts = productIds.ToDictionary(p => p, p => new List<string>(productCategories));

Comment: I guess you need some filtering on the second part.

Comment: @JTunney that's nearly equivalent, yes (it will be `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`).  Though still not convinced every product should have the same categories, but that may be correct in your use case.

Comment: Yep that would be it. So now what were you saying? That in C# the TSource, TKey are reversed and I was trying to specify them still? I think seeing it with everything specified now would make things more clear. Unless it isn't possible and I have to just let it be inferred.

Comment: See the signature of the method. Use `ToDictionary<List<string>, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(...)`.

Comment: Can you update your answer if possible. I really appreciate you guys helping me through something so stupid.

Comment: Thanks but it still errors saying IEnumerable<string> does not contain a definition for ToDictionary and also why are we putting a another dictionary within ToDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that both arguments need to be predicates, as such:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> missingProducts =
    productIds.ToDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(
        p => p, 
        p = > new List<string>(productCategories));
```

EDIT: My apologies for the duplicate answer, i missed the other while i was typing up this one, although i may be able to help you with your new problem, to avoid giving every value the same list, you can do some kind of comparison mechanism to predicate "p" as such:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> missingProducts =
    productIds.ToDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(
        p => p, 
        p = > productCategories.Where(category => category {someOperationHere} p));
```

Or if you have some kind of master list of categories, i dont know what you have exactly but:

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> missingProducts =
    productIds.ToDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>(
        p => p, 
        p = > masterCategories.Where(category => p.categories.Contains(category)));
```

Comment: I know vb is weird, but any idea why the version I posed doesn't error in intellisense? And there's no way to simply convert exactly what is there to c#?

Comment: productCategories is a hardcoded list created beforehand so it will always be the same for each productId. I updated the vb version exactly from the code.

Comment: It wont error in intellisense because a predicate is just a substitute for a method, so when you pass a method, it doesn't see anything wrong there

Comment: So which one of your 3 answers is the equivalent?

Comment: They all are, but they are guesses based on how your code could look. I have no idea what your code looks like, you only presented a few lines and i dont know what else you are working with.